# Making the bounding box visible outside the canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, canvas, fabricjs

Now I am aware that comparing features with completely different platforms might not be great, but I am curious if anyone out there has solved any similar issues. So just to raise an example, when selecting an object on `www.canva.com` and dragging the object outside of the canvas, the bounding box is still being displayed, see attached image.

[image]

And I know that this is possible on Fabric JS although I haven't been able to reproduce it consistently. So my question is quite short if anyone has solved this similar issue. Currently when I drag an object outside of the canvas, the bounding box disappears on the edge of the canvas.

## **Edit**

Currently the bounding box ends wherever the canvas ends.

[image]

But I think when I shrink the canvas, I manage to get a bounding box that is outside of the canvas, however, it is not a bounding box that I can really control. This is my closest attempt so far.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of what you've tried?

Comment: Most of what I have tried has not yielded any results. Except for one solution where I changed the width and height of the canvas. In those cases I could see that the bounding box could be outside of the canvas. Let me add some images in the edit section of the original question.